Website parent child relationship
My client has a well established Wordpress website which is currently set out as below:
website/properties/property-development-name/unit
We have been advised for SEO purposes that rather than the above parent child relationship we should change to the following
website/property-tenture/location/property-development-name/unit
Obviously there are several different housing developments with individual units for sale, with differing tenures, such as rentals and private sales etc. All in differing locations. I have been told it's not possible to have this file hierarchy in wordpress. I just wanted to ask the experts on here if there is a suitable way to achieve this, and if it is achieved, will it provide worthwhile SEO benefits.
Thank you in advance.

They aren't "files" or "folders" per se, but you could achieve that URL structure. Custom code to create custom post types and taxonomies would be the ideal way, as that could then be filtered, searched, etc. However, you could also do this in a no-code way by adding Pages at each level.
It's difficult to answer the "will it be worth it for SEO?" question canonically. Generally speaking, in most cases, if you have a well-established URL structure, SEO suffers when that structure is changed unless that established structure was incredibly poorly organized and bad for user experience. It is likely that any SEO gains you might eventually achieve would not be worth the hefty effort of reorganizing everything and painstakingly 301 redirecting everything. It is also almost certain that SEO algorithms will continue to evolve, so even if you did see gains, it's equally likely those gains may be negated in the future when other ranking signals take precedence.

Thank you @WebElanie :)

Customers generally google search for properties by location. i.e. City or Town. So would moving 'location' up to the top of the hierarchy worth reordering the content of the site structure in your opinion? I just want to make sure my clients allotted budget is spent in the best possible way.
